# How can I set a the Text View back to the original place after it moves a little bit?

Tags: android, timer, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I'm kind of new, but having a really good time figuring this stuff out.  Hope you don't mind helping me where I'm stuck.

Here is my OnTouchListener.  It is for the display of a timer and I want the timer to turn off if someone moves the view that displays the time.

I need it so that the view is moved past a certain point and then it implements.  Otherwise it gets a little confused with the a click gesture.  I'm going to set it so that the timer pauses on click.

The problem is.  I'll set the view as "GONE", so that you won't see it after it moves, but I still need the view to go back to it's original place so that when the next timer is started again, it will be reset.

```
    //setOnTouchListener Here
    zoneATimerText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    destroyCountDownTimer();
                    view.animate()
                            .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                            .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                    Log.v("on move", "you're moving");
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if you save the first place where timer be there?
Then when timer is out, set it back to that place and `setVisibility` to `visible`?

Answer (score 0):

Save the original position of the view i.e x,y at class level, and when your animation is done you hide the view with visibility gone at that time simply reset the position position of the view with method(view.setX(),view.setY()).